# I'm unable to use Keras weights to calculate the value predicted by the model

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to get a clear understanding of how I can use the weights produced by a Keras model to calculate a result in Python (i.e. without using the Keras model to predict). When I have simpler cases than the one below (2 features with no hidden layer or 1 feature with a hidden layer) I get the result I expect (my calculated value is the same as the model predicted value).  In the code below the output values don't agree. So I'm either not understanding or not seeing something. If a patient person could please explain in simple English how I can do this I'd be most gratified.

**Example Code (with 2 features and 1 hidden layer)**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy

# sigmoid function: nonlinearity.   
def nonlin(x, deriv = False):
    if (deriv == True): 
        return x * (1 - x)
    return 1 / (1 + numpy.exp(-x))

# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(5)
# load dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("values2.txt", delimiter=",") # 4 samples 2 factors 1 y
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:2]
Y = dataset[:,2]
# create model (1 hidden layer)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=2, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=200, batch_size=1)
# calculate predictions
predictions = model.predict(X)
# round predictions
rounded = [round(x[0]) for x in predictions]
#print(rounded)
#model.summary()
for layer in model.layers:
    weights = layer.get_weights() # list of numpy arrays
    print(weights)
M = model.get_weights()
# Example where X = 0 ()
print (X[0,0], X[0,1], "=", Y[0])
L1 = numpy.array([ [0.0], [0.0] ]) # to hold result of input * weights
L1[0] = X[0,0] * M[0][0][0] + X[0,1] * M[0][1][0] + M[1][0]
L1[1] = X[0,0] * M[0][0][1] + X[0,1] * M[0][1][1] + M[1][1]
L2 = numpy.array([ [0.0] ])
L2[0] = L1[0] * M[2][0][0] + L1[1] * M[2][1][0] + M[3][0]
print (nonlin(L2[0]), predictions[0]) # compare
```

**Input (Values2.txt: the first x determines the y)**

```
0,0,0
0,1,0
1,0,1
1,1,1
```

**Output**
...

```
Epoch 200/200
4/4 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.4380 - acc: 1.0000     
[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[array([[ 1.69063699,  0.1998844 ],
       [ 0.07858475,  0.89751321]], dtype=float32), array([-0.00052627, -0.17762977], dtype=float32)]
[array([[ 0.83898878],
       [-0.54218996]], dtype=float32), array([-0.05681464], dtype=float32)]
0.0 0.0 = 0.0
[ 0.50976198] [ 0.48580015]
```

Thanks Matias Valdenegro

In response to you comments I have changed the code to the following and it produces the desired output. I changed the activation from relu to sigmoid in the first layer and used the nonlin function on the results of the first layer when using them in the second layer. Is that correct?

**Modified code**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy

# sigmoid function: nonlinearity.   
def nonlin(x, deriv = False):
    if (deriv == True): 
        return x * (1 - x)
    return 1 / (1 + numpy.exp(-x))

# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(5)
# load dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("values2.txt", delimiter=",") # 4 samples 2 factors 1 y
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:2]
Y = dataset[:,2]
# create model (1 hidden layer)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=2, activation='sigmoid')) 
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=200, batch_size=1)
# calculate predictions
predictions = model.predict(X)
# round predictions
rounded = [round(x[0]) for x in predictions]
#print(rounded)
#model.summary()
for layer in model.layers:
    weights = layer.get_weights() # list of numpy arrays
    print(weights)
M = model.get_weights()
# Example where X = 0 ()
print (X[0,0], X[0,1], "=", Y[0])
L1 = numpy.array([ [0.0], [0.0] ]) # to hold result of input * weights
L1[0] = X[0,0] * M[0][0][0] + X[0,1] * M[0][1][0] + M[1][0]
L1[1] = X[0,0] * M[0][0][1] + X[0,1] * M[0][1][1] + M[1][1]
L2 = numpy.array([ [0.0] ])
L2[0] = nonlin(L1[0]) * M[2][0][0] + nonlin(L1[1])  * M[2][1][0] + M[3][0]
print (nonlin(L2[0]), predictions[0]) # compare
```

**Output from modified code**

```
Epoch 200/200
4/4 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6463 - acc: 1.0000     
[array([[ 1.70278633,  0.0848918 ],
       [-0.0271775 ,  0.92663836]], dtype=float32), array([-0.14723039,  0.00718958], dtype=float32)]
[array([[ 0.56880862],
       [-0.60756117]], dtype=float32), array([ 0.03559623], dtype=float32)]
0.0 0.0 = 0.0
[ 0.4985573] [ 0.4985573]
```

**I added a ReLU function** (x * (x > 0))
The calculation is now as follows and produces the expected results.

```
L1 = numpy.array([ [0.0], [0.0] ]) # to hold result of input * weights
L1[0] = relu(X[0,0] * M[0][0][0] + X[0,1] * M[0][1][0] + M[1][0])
L1[1] = relu(X[0,0] * M[0][0][1] + X[0,1] * M[0][1][1] + M[1][1])
L2 = numpy.array([ [0.0] ])
L2[0] = L1[0] * M[2][0][0] + L1[1]  * M[2][1][0] + M[3][0]
print (nonlin(L2[0]), predictions[0])
```

Thanks. (Assuming that's the basic answer I'm not sure what I should do to mark something as an answer here...?)

Comment: I don't see you applying the ReLU in your python code. That is probably the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I've modified my code in response. See edits.

Comment: Still no relu in the new code...

Comment: I think I know what you mean... I'll have another go when I get a chance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm not sure why no one wanted to answer this question, I don't want to leave it unanswered so I'll just express what I understand of what Matias and Daniel have already said)

When multiplying the weights in a neural network to find the value of the nodes of each layer you need to remember to include the activation function which is usually a ReLU function (rectified linear unit)(aka ramp function).